# Phonegap ajax GET returning Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, cordova

Im building an app with Phonegap and Backbone which parses an external XML feed. The feed is at:

```
http://cbccork.schoolspace.ie/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=1&format=raw
```

I fetch with:

```
var news = new model.NewsCollection();

news.fetch({
    full_url: true,
    success: function (collection) {
        slider.slidePage(new NewsList({collection: collection}).$el);
    },
    error: function (model, response, options) {
        console.log('statusText is ');
        console.log(response.statusText);
        console.log('responseText is ');
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
});
```

This works fine. However, the subdomain will be removed soon so the feed url will become:

```
http://cbccork.ie/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=1&format=raw
```

If you go to the urls you will see the output is the same xml (with http://cbccork.ie/ instead of http://cbccork.schoolspace.ie/).

However, when testing on an Android device, nothing is returned. I printed out the response which is:

```
Value of responseText is 
Value of responseXML is null
Value of status is 500
Value of statusText is Internal Server Error
```

I have tested this in chrome (by disabling the same origin policy) and it works. But on any android device, it will not work.

I have been trying to solve this for 3 days and am completely stumped. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

The news model and collection looks like this:

```
define(function (require) {

"use strict";

var $                   = require('jquery'),
    Backbone            = require('backbone'),
    id=1,
    xml,
    parsed = [], 
    title = "", 
    description = "",
    pubDate = "", 
    src="",
    img="",

    News = Backbone.Model.extend({  

    }),


    NewsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: News,
        //url: 'http://www.test.webintelligence.ie/test/',

        url: 'http://www.cbccork.ie/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=1&format=raw',

        //This is used so I can test on a browser. On a device, use the direct link   
      /*
        url: function(){
             console.log('in news');
                return "/school-proxy.php?type=news";
             },*/


        parse: function (data) {

            xml = data;


            $(xml).find('item').each(function (index) {


                img = $(description).find('img:first');

                src = img.attr('src');

                if(typeof(src)==='undefined' || src===null || src===""){
                    //so its null or undefined
                    src = "img/crest.jpg";
                }

                title = $(this).find('title').text();

                description = $(this).find('description').text();

                pubDate = $(this).find('pubDate').text();

                pubDate = pubDate.substring(0, pubDate.length-12);


                parsed.push({id:id, title: title, 
                            description:description, pubDate:pubDate, src:src});
                title, description, pubDate, src, img = "";

               id++;
            });

            return parsed;
        },


        fetch: function (options) {

            options = options || {};
            options.dataType = "xml";
            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }

    });


return {
    News: News,
    NewsCollection: NewsCollection
};

});
```

**EDIT:**

I tried a direct Ajax call, but yet again I get an Internal Server Error on an Android device:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.cbccork.ie/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=1&format=raw",
          })
            .done(function( data ) {

                console.log( "Sample of data:", data );

            })
            .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

                console.log('in the fail, textstatus is ');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log('error throwen is ');
                console.log(errorThrown);

            });
```

Is there any way of solving this? I have tried everything...

Comment: Just a thought - Have you properly listed your URL in Domain WhiteListing ?

Comment: Yep, in config.xml I have <access origin="*" />. I have also tried other url's, which all work fine...

Comment: how do you declare and configure "news" before calling the fetch method, can you past some more code?

Comment: @homtg - I have edited the question. When I change the url, "parse" in the collection is never entered...

Comment: Perhaps the other server requires some HTTP Headers that are not required by the first one?

Comment: Both urls work through the browser. How would I find out if HTTP headers are needed?

Comment: I had also faced same problem. Try it in a device not in emulator ...... If it will not solve your problem then give me your whole initialize() function i will check it..

Comment: I have tried on 2 android devices and I get the same error. But if i use the subdomain, it works! The only thing I change is removal of subdomain and it stops working. I have no idea why. Which initialise() function do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Joomla Mobile plugin was turned on but not configured correctly meaning no xml was returned when queried from a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

just tried it from my pc and this is the result:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.cbccork.ie/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=1&format=raw. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.2.121' is therefore not allowed access.
```

there is no doubt that your server is not configured for CORS. you not only have to allow your script to access other domains, but your server should also be configured for being accessed from other domains.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to get xml through ajax GET and convert to JSON for hadle it easier?

Perhaps it would help to find the error.

Comment: $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.cbccork.ie/index.php?option=com_ninjarsssyndicator&feed_id=3&format=raw",
              })
                .done(function( data ) {
           
                    console.log( "Sample of data:", data );
                  
                })
                .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
         
                    console.log('error throwen is ');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    
                });

Comment: I think could be a server config problem.

Comment: ya perhaps it is as i noticed the website isn't working properly on mobile devices